# Function listitem.getMeasuredHeight() gives me the height of only one line, as listitem is edittext

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm displaying `listview` inside `scrollview`,and i'm setting height of `listview` in java code using `listitem.getMeasuredHeight()` 
=> `listItem` is `editText`
if user press enter button then it measure correct height but if user enters text in `editText` without pressing enter button then this method consider the text in one line and gives me height of one line and it display double-scrolling

i also tried the previous question discussed in stackoverflow but not helpful

i also set attribute of `scrollview` - `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
    YourPersonalSkillsAdapter yourPersonalSkillsAdapter = new 
YourPersonalSkillsAdapter(this,PersonalSkillsArrayList());

ListView personalSkillslistView=
(ListView)findViewById(R.id.s_YourPersonalSkillsListView_id);
personalSkillslistView.setAdapter(yourPersonalSkillsAdapter);
justifyPersonalSkillsListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(personalSkillslistView);



public static void justifyYourEducationListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter adapter = (YourEducationAdapter) listView.getAdapter();

        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        ViewGroup vg = listView;

        int totalHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, vg);

            listItem.measure(0, 0);

            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();

        par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() *(adapter.getCount() - 1));

        listView.setLayoutParams(par);

        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

i expect the output to measure correct width and height of `listview` item

Comment: You'd be better off switching to use `NestedScrollView` + `RecyclerView`, as RecyclerView works "out of the box" with `wrap_content` height. Then you wouldn't have to worry about this problem at all.

Comment: After switching to RecyclerView, i get rid of this problem Thanks Ben P